# Measuring Difference when AB Testing is not ideal

Tags: hypothesis-testing

Normally it is best to be able to set up a randomized AB test to measure if some change is actually better than the original.  What about in situations where it is not ideal to AB test?

For example, we are a ride sharing company operating in an area where the amount of drivers are much lower than the amount of people looking for rides, and we want to test a new pricing algorithm and measure the impact of it.  Splitting our users into a control and test group will make it more difficult to meet the already higher than supply demand, and different pricing between drivers may incite negative feedback and complaints on the uneven payments.  There can also be many difficulties when it comes to controlling variables such as distances from drivers to riders while trying to randomize our test and control groups.

In events like this, which technique would be ideal to be able to measure a difference with some degree of certainty?

Comment: Could you clarify a  bit what you mean? I'm concerned that this question might be closed because it is hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: Presumably this depends on the type of "fragility" you mean and how this restricts what can be done? Are you meaning something like "only small changes are permitted"?

Comment: You can minimize the adverse effects of changes by experimenting on only as many actual customers as necessary. You can also minimize the amount of changes from one algorithm to the other. They should not be completely different.

Comment: I edited my example to hopefully clarify the question.

Comment: This seems more like a substantive question for marketing or business than it is about statistics per se. I don't know if the people on the [economics.SE] SE site might have some insights.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to reflect revised interpretation of question**

If the algorithms were selected based on some mathematical model of consumer behavior, that same model might be used to evaluate the new algorithm and compare its projections directly to the old algorithm. If no model currently exists, one could be developed and, if it performs well enough predicting usage under the current algorithm, then used to estimate effects of the new algorithm.

Without such a model, I might do something like conduct a survey of potential customers asking about how much they might use the ride share service under the current surge pricing algorithm as well as the new one. Their responses regarding the current algorithm can be compared against data collected from real observations of use (also under the current algorithm) to estimate how well the stated preferences match actual use. The answers to questions about the new algorithm allow for estimation of the new algorithm's performance, mediated by the differences between stated and revealed preferences regarding the current algorithm.

I don't doubt that there are a lot of other approaches, but this strikes me as a question that's hard to answer in the general case. Modeling is a formal way of examining the relevant factors' effects on the outcome, but your predictions will only be as accurate as the underlying model. Surveys are effective in some applications and less so in others. I don't know if there is a single "ideal" technique for projecting the effect of a potential change like you describe unless the question is substantially narrowed.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of the question. They are saying that changing the algorithm for a subset of users can drastically affect business profits. It isn't like investigating clickstream data.

Comment: I may be missing the point of the question. My reading was: how can we compare the performance of algorithm A and algorithm B when conditions may differ for each? This was based on the question tag and the wording "measure a difference", which implies that both algorithms have been deployed. In such a case, I would try to define relevant factors and then account for them to extract the effect of the new algorithm on profits.

If the question is about *projecting* the effects of a new algorithm rather than testing, my answer is indeed off point. Am I interpreting your comment correctly?

Comment: Yes the user would like to compare algorithm A to B, but realizes that they may have a sensitive use-case and are looking for alternatives. Let's say algorithm B is terrible. Let's say it makes people want to not use the service anymore. They just ruined their business by experimenting on actual customers.

Comment: Thank you Pierre, that interpretation seems more sound. I've edited my response.

Comment: That's an interesting question. I was wondering the same for a while. :/